# CORS error despite having allowed the origin

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an Angular app that runs on an aspnetcore webapi. The webapi is configured with origins to localhost:4200 so I can run on my machine. Ultimately when it is deployed, it is deployed as a single api and therefore doesn't require CORS.

However when running locally I get CORS errors:

[image]

[image]

I have the api configured for windows auth as it is a local intranet but I get this error whether the controller has the Authenticate attribute or not.

My CORS config:

```cs
private static readonly string[] _origins = { "http://localhost", "http://localhost:3278", "http://localhost:4200" };
services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder => builder.WithOrigins(_origins).AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials()));
app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins(_origins).AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials());
```

Using a typical Startup.cs config.

Everything works perfectly when deployed - this is a local issue only because it is only locally that it uses CORS. Driving me nuts!

Fairly recent angular install:

[image]

and a .net7 Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web app for the webapi.

Any ideas??

Comment: Have you cheked https and http configuration? How is your middleware order could you please include those?

Comment: I can see your request url containing `http://localhost:4200/` additional trail slash `/` which shouldn't be there , have you tried with `http://localhost:4200`? instead of `http://localhost:4200/`?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron here is my whole startup.cs https://hastebin.skyra.pw/lufigonexo.pgsql - and yes i thought the same thing and tried that - no luck im afraid

Comment: Also just to note I just changed it to Kestrel just to make it as vanilla as pos so this startup doesnt 100% match the previous one the rest of the post is about but I can post that too if it is useful. The site is http, no https.

Comment: To be clear on the slash - I tried adding the slash to the allowed origins; i didnt try removing it from the request, because angular is controlling that - i dont know how i would control it?

Comment: It kinda looks to me like you are receiving an authentication error (requires auth with NTLM/Negotiate). Sometimes CORS errors show up in the log even though it isn't the core reason for the error.

Comment: @juunas i agree thats what i thought but its the same with or without the authorise attribute. I can try to strip out all auth but I obviously need the auth. It works once deployed on a single origin which is why it DOES appear to be CORS related...

Comment: as a workaround you can do what I do... create a Chrome profile with CORS turned off and use that for local debugging. (helps reduce the risk of adding CORS to live site, too)  Down-side is you won't be able to debug front-end from IDE... I just use alerts and piped errors to console.log for that.